# How to I find a certain element in an array and change it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a function to find the element "Tolkn" and change it to "Tolkien".

```
changeName = (arr) => {
  if (arr === "Tolkn") {
    arr.push("Tolkien")
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function like this

```js
let arr = ['test', 'test2', 'Tolkn', 'test3'];


let changeName = (inpArr) => {
  let index = inpArr.findIndex(function(itm) {
    return itm == 'Tolkn';
  })
  if (index === -1) {
    return inpArr;
  }
  inpArr[index] = 'Tolkien';
  return inpArr;
};

console.log(changeName(arr));
```

Another way with `forEach`

```js
let arr = ['test', 'test2', 'Tolkn', 'test3'];

function changeName(arr) {
  let output = [];
  arr.forEach(function(itm) {
    if (itm == "Tolkn") {
      output.push("Tolkien")
    } else {
      output.push(itm);
    }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(changeName(arr));
```

Comment: This kind of works but doesn't pass all the tests I need it to pass.

Comment: I got it to work. Is there a simpler way to go about this though?

Comment: If you want change only one element with something else, the first one is good. but if you have more than one, use second one with a `switch case` or `if else` conditions. @batman091716

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee you don't need to `return arr` in the first version.  You're modifying the array in place.  I mention this because I think it's misleading to have the return, which might be misread as returning a _new_ array, leaving the input untouched.

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem. Update my answer or explain more please @MattMorgan

Comment: @Saeed.Ataee your first code example modifies the array that was passed as input.  You don't need to `return` this array, because the outer scope already contains a reference to it.  People will disagree about _if_ this is a good idea, but when you do something like this, you should really be as clear as possible:  you aren't making a new array, you're changing the original one.  Your second code example makes a new array, leaving the original one untouched, so of course you need to return it.

Answer (score 1):

Making a copy with correct values (now in an even more concise form thanks to @MattMorgan).

```js
var arr = ["Tolkn","a","some","Tolkn"];
var changeName = arr.map.bind(arr, elem => elem === "Tolkn" ? "Tolkien" : elem);
arr = changeName(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Or in place replacement:

```js
var arr = ["Tolkn","a","some","Tolkn"];
var changeName = arr.forEach.bind(arr, (val, ind) => {arr[ind] = (val === "Tolkn" ? "Tolkien" : val)});
changeName(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: you could simplify your first function (no need for `return`) to `var changeName = arr.map.bind(arr, elem => elem === "Tolkn" ? "Tolkien" : elem);`

Comment: @MattMorgan Strangely enough, I did try that first and got back a syntax error. Seems to work now though.

Answer (score 0):

Short version if you don't mind a possible hidden "-1" property:

```js
let changeName = arr => (arr[arr.indexOf("Tolkn")] = "Tolkien", arr)

console.log( changeName( ['Tolkn'] ) )  // ['Tolkien']
console.log( changeName( ['Talkn'] ) )  // ['Talkn']
```